# List disk devices in tree form

Tags: sata

how can I list all disk devices in a tree hierarchy, grouped by controller? For example, with 2 PCI 4port SATA cards + 2 SATA disks attached to the motherboard, I'd like to see something like:

```
---- mobo SATA controller
|    |- mobo port 1: WD80EFZX sda
|    \- mobo port 2: WD80EFZX sdb
---- PCIe SATA controller #1
|    |- card1 port 1: WD80EFZX sdc
|    |- card1 port 2: WD80EFZX sdd
|    |- card1 port 3: WD80EFZX sdf
|    \- card1 port 4: WD80EFZX sde
\--- PCIe SATA controller #2
     |- card1 port 1: WD80EFZX sdg
     |- card1 port 2: WD80EFZX sdi
     |- card1 port 3: WD80EFZX sdj
     \- card1 port 4: WD80EFZX sdk
```

Using sdX gets hairy because it sometimes messes stuff up when there's a USB stick attached at boot ... so some way of addressing the sd-device by controller id similar to the persistent networking interface names would be nice.

Comment: See [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/90324) from Unix StackExchange

Comment: Doesn't help - I need an association between controller port and sd-device identifier.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that /dev/disk/by-path contains symlinks to the sdX files, which contain the PCI/USB controller ID and port... not exactly the output I wanted, but I can use it to get the association sdX=>portID.